# Why don't I get the desired output? In this recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I've been doing this course on Udacity and this one problem has been stressing me for a while and I don't know why this keeps coming back to me and I can't really get a idea of it due to the fact that I find recursive functions super confusing and complicated.

I would like to find the solution by myself but I need some help to how this works and why it doesn't output in my desired manner. Thank you.

```
# Single Gold Star

# Family Trees

# In the lecture, we showed a recursive definition for your ancestors. For this
# question, your goal is to define a procedure that finds someone's ancestors,
# given a Dictionary that provides the parent relationships.

# Here's an example of an input Dictionary:

ada_family = { 'Judith Blunt-Lytton': ['Anne Isabella Blunt', 'Wilfrid Scawen Blunt'],
              'Ada King-Milbanke': ['Ralph King-Milbanke', 'Fanny Heriot'],
              'Ralph King-Milbanke': ['Augusta Ada King', 'William King-Noel'],
              'Anne Isabella Blunt': ['Augusta Ada King', 'William King-Noel'],
              'Byron King-Noel': ['Augusta Ada King', 'William King-Noel'],
              'Augusta Ada King': ['Anne Isabella Milbanke', 'George Gordon Byron'],
              'George Gordon Byron': ['Catherine Gordon', 'Captain John Byron'],
              'John Byron': ['Vice-Admiral John Byron', 'Sophia Trevannion'] }

# Define a procedure, ancestors(genealogy, person), that takes as its first input
# a Dictionary in the form given above, and as its second input the name of a
# person. It should return a list giving all the known ancestors of the input
# person (this should be the empty list if there are none). The order of the list
# does not matter and duplicates will be ignored.

output = []
def ancestors(genealogy, person):
    if person in genealogy:
        for candidate in genealogy[person]:
            output.append(candidate)
            ancestors(genealogy, candidate)
        return output
    else:
        return []




# Here are some examples:

print (ancestors(ada_family, 'Augusta Ada King'))
#>>> ['Anne Isabella Milbanke', 'George Gordon Byron',
#    'Catherine Gordon','Captain John Byron']

print (ancestors(ada_family, 'Judith Blunt-Lytton'))
#>>> ['Anne Isabella Blunt', 'Wilfrid Scawen Blunt', 'Augusta Ada King',
#    'William King-Noel', 'Anne Isabella Milbanke', 'George Gordon Byron',
#    'Catherine Gordon', 'Captain John Byron']

print (ancestors(ada_family, 'Dave'))
#>>> []
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare output within the function scope. Otherwise it's not resetting.

Comment: How will that work then? it's a recursive function right?? thus, everytime the function is called it would create an empty list removing the previously appended items.

Comment: Create an outer function around it. Otherwise it should work for the first function call but will not reset for any later ones